# Need to add Authentication details in the header section of request XML SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, client

I want to add the following Authentication header in my soap request:

```
<soap:Header>
<AuthHeader xmlns="abcd">
<UserID>abcd</UserID>
<User_Password> abcd</User_Password>
<CorrespondentID>abcd</CorrespondentID>
</AuthHeader>
</soap:Header>
```

I am calling a web service which requires authentication and I have to explicitly set the above given authentication header to the request XML.

Please help me with the java code?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using JAX-WS (or compliant library). You need to write a message handler and attach it to the handler chain. The handler can access the message headers and insert your security tokens in the outbound message. Here is a link on how to write appropriate jax-ws handlers. http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Working-with-Headers-in-JAX-WS-SOAPHandlers.aspx

EDIT: Following link shows how to add a custom header in a JAX-WS Soap client. 
http://www.javadb.com/using-a-message-handler-to-alter-the-soap-header-in-a-web-service-client

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the response,but, I am not able to get the current instance of MessageContext. 
Here I need to use the current instance of the MessageContext.
I do not have much knowledge about the internal flow of generated client code.

Comment: @Bimalesh The question is related to accessing a `Web Service` from a client application rather than implementing a handler code in the `Web Service`

Comment: @user182944 Even web service clients can implement a handler. Handler is not restricted to server side of WS. Why the down vote?

Comment: @Aditya You have the handle to Soap client proxy in your code. From the proxy you get the bindng provider of the SOAP runtime. From binding provider you can configure the handler chain. Implement you own handler and attach to the handler chain.

Comment: @user182944 you can update you knowledge about jax-ws by reading up links like these http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13734/handlers.htm#i267848 before adding needles comments or downvotes.